# Statistical model for quantities that add up to 1

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, modeling, references, terminology

I want to create a model for quantities $z$ that live in a probability simplex, that is, they are nonnegative and always add up to 1:

$$ S = \left\{z \in \mathbb{R}^{k} : z_1 + \dots + z_{k} = 1, z_i \ge 0 \text{ for } i = 1, \dots, k \right\},$$  where $k$ is relatively small, let's say $k \leq 5$.

Additionally, I know these values come from a black box process where I only know some details about it, e.g. an input array of the form: $(x_1,  \ldots, x_k)$ with additional features $(\theta_1,  \ldots, \theta_k)$ where again, $(x_1,  \ldots, x_k)$ are nonnegative and add up to one (notice it's also of dimension $k$).

For modelling purposes let's assume we got samples of all these arrays ($x$, $z$ and $\theta$) as time series (always all values measured at the same time), and additionally we know that:

1. There's a dependence of the $z$ array from the $x$'s and $\theta$'s, but with a lag, that is, $z_t$ depends on the previous time values of $x$ and $\theta$. This lag is not constant over time but it can't grow indefinitely either, let's say it's a maximum of $N$ previous timestamps where $N$ < 10
2. The $z$ and $x$ quantities are relative rates, not really probabilities
3. The output $z$ is somehow a mixture of the input $x$ of previous timestamps, e.g. $z_i^T$ will depend strongly on the respective $x_i^{t}$ for recent values $T-N \leq t \leq T-1$, and their associated parameters inside $\theta_i^{t}$ (that correspond to the $i$t-h quantity). But it won't be necessarily inside their convex combination, i.e. it could happen that the $z_i^{T}$ lies outside the minimum and maximum values of the recent $x_i^{t}$ values

I think that taking ideas from the following fields can be useful:

1. Graphical models - with $k$ (or $k-1$) output nodes
2. Neural networks - use a multilayer perceptron using an idea similar to the softmax activation function
3. Generalized additive models (create something similar to the multinomial logit model but with a response variable that isn't a classification response but probabilities)
4. Multivariate time series - but I'm not familiar with ways to impose the bounds that the series are between 0 and 1 and also the add-up-to-1 condition into the modelling framework

And I wonder if there's already some literature or known model for this kind of processes (nonnegative continuous variables that add up to a fixed quantity), but my search hasn't brought results yet. Do you have any pointers to relevant modelling approaches?

Comment: Have you come across [compositional data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data)?

Comment: As @awhug, your response data is on a simplex.

Comment: Hi @awhug thanks for the suggestion, yes, had found that same wikipedia article earlier and it looked promising. I see there are several R and Python libraries, will dig further into that field

Comment: Dirichlet Regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As others have written](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/547909/statistical-model-for-quantities-that-add-up-to-1#comment1006337_547909), this is *compositional data analysis*. We have a [compositional-data](/questions/tagged/compositional-data) tag, so searching for [threads carrying, e.g., this tag and the "time-series" one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compositional-data+time-series) may be helpful.

One paper on forecasting compositional time series is [Snyder et al. (2017, *IJF*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2016.11.008). Essentially, the idea is to transform the original compositional time series, then forecast the transformed data, and finally back-transform the forecasts in a way that respects the compositional nature. Thus, this approach should also work with other forecasting methods, like neural networks, or anything that uses lags or causal effects.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. That paper's quite interesting